# How to validate all elements of an array in stubMatchers

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

```
Contract.make {
    request {
        method 'POST'
        urlPath '/for/post'
        body("""
            [
                {
                    "duck": "1"
                },
                {
                    "duck": "2"
                },
                {
                    "duck": "3"
                }
            ]
        """)
        stubMatchers {
            jsonPath('$[*].duck', byRegex(nonEmpty()))
//            jsonPath('$[0].duck', byRegex(nonEmpty()))
//            jsonPath('$[1].duck', byRegex(nonEmpty()))
//            jsonPath('$[2].duck', byRegex(nonEmpty()))
        }
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
    response {
        status 200
        body([
                duck: 123
        ])
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
}
```

If I use "$[*].duck", as long as one of them is not empty, it will return data . So I use "$[0].duck, $[1].duck, $[2].duck". How can I make it more concise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no other way because of jsonpath. You're doing it properly.